# React + PostgreSQL + Node.js inserting Checkbox value on database

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, database, postgresql

I am trying for the first time to insert values of a checkbox in a database using React, PostgreSQL and Node.js. I'm having a hard time dealing with the back-end part of it and structuring how it would work.

On the terminal, I'm getting the following error: "ForbiddenError: invalid csrf token" (which I have faced a couple of times before and fixed by cleaning the cookies and logging in again) and on the console: "POST http://localhost:8080/voteforfiji 403 (Forbidden)" plus a Catch, from the catch chunk of my post route.

Anyone here who has done this before and would be able to explain how should it be done? Here's what I've tried so far:

**table.sql**

```
CREATE TABLE fiji(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    vote BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

**db.js**

```
exports.addVoteForFiji = function(vote_for_fiji) {
  return db
    .query(
      `INSERT INTO fiji (vote_for_fiji)
    VALUES ($1)`,
      [vote_for_fiji]
    )
    .then(data => {
      return data.rows;
    });
};
```

**index.js route**

```
app.post("/voteforfiji", (req, res) => {
  let body = req.body;
  db.addVoteForFiji(req.session.userId, body.vote_for_fiji)
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data);
      res.json({ success: true });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
      res.json({
        success: false
      });
    });
});
```

**honeymoon.js React Component**

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

export default class Honeymoon extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      error: false,
      vote: "VOTE . ",
      votar: "VOTAR . ",
      stimmen: "STIMMEN ",
      checked: false
    };

    this.changeMessage = this.changeMessage.bind(this);
  }

  changeMessage(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    axios
      .post("/voteforfiji", this.state)
      .then(res => {
        console.log("res from axios.post/addinfo", res);
        this.setState({
          vote: "THANK YOU!    ",
          votar: "OBRIGADO!    ",
          stimmen: "DANKESCHÖN!",
          checked: true
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error("error in honeymoon:", error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    const home = <img src="home.png" />;
    const mail = <img src="mail.png" />;

    function AllOtherComponentsMenu() {
      return (
        <nav className="header-on-app">
          <button>
            <Link to="/">{home}</Link>
          </button>
          <button>{mail}</button>
          <button className="logout-btn">
            <a href="/logout">Logout</a>
          </button>
        </nav>
      );
    }

    return (
      <div className="honeymoon-container">
        <AllOtherComponentsMenu />

        <h1 className="title-all-pages">Kathi & Rodolfo</h1>
        <h2 className="subtitle-all-pages">
          <span>_______</span> Honeymoon . Lua de Mel . Hochzeitsreise
          <span>_______</span>
        </h2>
        {this.state.error && <h2>Ops! Something went wrong.</h2>}

        <h2 className="honeymoon-subtitle">
          It is no secret: we love travelling! Help us to decide if we&apos;re
          going to Fiji or Patagonia for our Honeymoon.
        </h2>
        <h2 className="honeymoon-subtitle">
          Não é nenhum segredo que nós adoramos viajar! Nos ajude a decidir se
          iremos de Lua de Mel para Fiji ou para Patagônia.
        </h2>
        <h2 className="honeymoon-subtitle">
          Es ist kein Geheimnis: Wir lieben es zu reisen! Entscheide mit, ob wir
          nach Fiji oder Patagonien reisen werden.
        </h2>

        <div className="grid-container-honeymoon">

          <div className="pool-box">
            <h2>YOU DECIDE . VOCÊ DECIDE . DU BESCHLIESST</h2>
            <p>
              It&apos;s time to vote! The votes are secret and we can&apos;t
              tell what your choice was. We will find out what&apos;s our
              destination on the wedding day, together with you!
            </p>
            <p>
              É hora de votar! Os votos são secretos e nós não sabemos qual foi
              a sua escolha. E nós vamos descobrir nosso destino no dia do
              casamento, junto com vocês!
            </p>
            <p>
              Es ist an der Zeit, abzustimmen! Eure Stimmen sind geheim und wir
              können Eure Entscheidungen nicht einsehen. Wir finden dann an
              unserem Hochzeitstage mit Euch zusammen heraus, wohin die Reise
              geht!
            </p>
            <br />

            <form method="post">
              <input type="checkbox" id="fiji" name="vote_for_fiji" />
              <label className="honeymoon-label" htmlFor="fiji">
                Fiji Islands / Ilhas Fiji / Fiji Inseln
              </label>
              <br />
              <button onClick={this.changeMessage} className="pool-btn">
                {this.state.vote} {this.state.votar}
                {this.state.stimmen}
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the issue with the current code? You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60748305/edit) to include the problem you're facing.

Comment: Thanks @cbr, I haven"t even realised that my question was poorly formulated. Done! Hopes it's clear now :)

Comment: The error suggests you're using some CSRF middleware. Maybe `csurf`? If you're using it, you'll need to provide the CSRF token that it provides. Take a look at its documentation. By the way, your SQL has an error, it should be `INSERT INTO fiji (vote)` instead of `INSERT INTO fiji (vote_for_fiji)` according to your schema.

Comment: The token works fine. It only started to bug when I added this route. Thanks for pointing the error on my SQL!

Comment: Well, do you have other POST routes? `csurf` ignores GET, HEAD, and OPTIONS requests.

Comment: Yes, I have two other POST routes and it's working fine. My code breaks when I reach this last route.